# sql order with join

Tags: sql, join

i have this sql query:

```
SELECT b.topbid, b.topdate, a.* 
FROM auction_items a 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT itemID, MAX(bid) as topbid, 
   MAX(date) as topdate FROM auction_bids GROUP BY itemID ) b 
ON a.id = b.itemID 
ORDER BY b.topdate DESC, a.date DESC LIMIT 20
```

It's not ordering how i'd like it to. I want it to order by merging `b.topdate` and `a.date`.

What is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "order by merging `a.topdate` and `b.date`"?

Comment: so if b.topdate is above a.date, it would come above it.

Comment: Then it looks as though that's what you've done:  `order by b.topdate desc,a.date desc`.

Comment: Can we see some sample data to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have it order by both b.topdate and a.date, because they could both have a value.  If you can say that when they both have a value that you should use one over the other (for instance topdate over date), you can do it like this:

```
SELECT b.topbid, b.topdate, a.* 
FROM auction_items a 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT itemID, MAX(bid) as topbid, 
   MAX(date) as topdate FROM auction_bids GROUP BY itemID ) b 
ON a.id = b.itemID 
ORDER BY COALESCE(b.topdate, a.date) DESC LIMIT 20
```

Note the order by.  If its the other way around, make it COALESCE(a.date, b.topdate)

Comment: so does that fix your issue then?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean order by concatenating the two values? if yes, try the following:

```
SELECT b.topbid, b.topdate, a.* 
FROM auction_items a 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT itemID, MAX(bid) as topbid, 
   MAX(date) as topdate FROM auction_bids GROUP BY itemID ) b 
ON a.id = b.itemID 
ORDER BY b.topdate || a.date DESC LIMIT 20
```

I am not sure what RDBMS you are in, but Oracle concatenation is pipes ||

EDIT: if using MySQL use the CONCAT function:

```
SELECT b.topbid, b.topdate, a.* 
    FROM auction_items a 
    LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT itemID, MAX(bid) as topbid, 
       MAX(date) as topdate FROM auction_bids GROUP BY itemID ) b 
    ON a.id = b.itemID 
    ORDER BY CONCAT(b.topdate,a.date) DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Looks like MySQL to me - not Oracle. Judging from the OP's question history it's almost certainly MySQL...

Comment: thanks, I never thought to check the op's history, good idea for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try Selecting one or the other using a CASE statement, then order by that value instead :

```
SELECT b.topbid, b.topdate, a.* , CASE WHEN b.topdate > a.date then b.topdate ELSE a.date     END AS oDate
FROM auction_items a 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT itemID, MAX(bid) as topbid, 
   MAX(date) as topdate FROM auction_bids GROUP BY itemID ) b 
ON a.id = b.itemID 
ORDER BY oDate DESC LIMIT 20
```